# Scipy Lapack - How to find the correct Lapack function

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I am trying to use the `scipy.linalg` package but without the overhead. The funtions I currently use are [scipy.linalg.cho_factor](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_factor.html) and [scipy.linalg.cho_solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_solve.html) for cholesky decomposition. I have to use `scipy.linalg.lapack` or `scipy.linalg.cython_lapack` (or even `blas`), especially for the latter function which is being called thousands of times.

The problem is I don't know where to start, since there are tons of functions and their names are encoded e.g. `cbbcsd`, `cbdsqr` etc. The question is: **how do you find the right function**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to look inside the Python/Cython code for `scipy.linalg.cho_factor` and see what it uses. For `cho_factor` it looks like [it might be `?potrf`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f1251aa680623c20efa95a530a8b02e729f6d8d9/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py#L36). The question mark is replaced with a letter depending on the data types.

More generally, if you know which operation you want to apply, the names are constructed pretty systematically. See http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug_old/node26.html and http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug_old/node26.html for example. Typically you have to know the data-type (single precision (i.e. float), double, complex, etc...), the symmetry (if any) of the matrices and then the operation.

BLAS is largely just multiplications of various combinations of matrices and vectors and some solutions of systems of linear equations, while Lapack is anything more advanced (decompositions, eigenvalues, etc).

Comment: Yeah, I looked in cho_factor... Seems sneaky...;P But thanks anyway...